# How to make a text file into a list of arrays (array-in-array) and remove spaces/newlines

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, file

For example I have a txt file:

```
3 2 7 4
1 8 9 3
6 5 4 1
1 0 8 7
```

On every line there are 4 numbers and there are 4 lines. At end of lines there's \n (except the last one). The code I have is:

```
f = input("Insert file name: ")
file = open(f, encoding="UTF-8")
```

What I want is the text file to become `[[3,2,7,4],[1,8,9,3],[6,5,4,1],[1,0,8,7]]`.

I have tried everything, I know the answer is probably really simple, but I just really give up after an hour of attempts. Tried `read()`, `readlines()`, `split()`, `splitlines()`, `strip()` and whatever else I could find on the internet. So many can't even make a difference between them...

Comment: Always use `with` statement for opening the files. It will close the file object at the end of the block automatically. Beside, you should use consider using `csv` module which is more suitable for this case. Read your file with `csv` and it will gives you an iterable contain all lines splitted. Then `list(reader_object)` will give  you the desire result.

Comment: looks like a duplicate, but not easy to find an original solving this. This is a good question because the title says it all, and the body is short & documented enough. Great first post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you opened the file, use this one-liner using `split` as you mentionned and nested list comprehension:

```
with open(f, encoding="UTF-8") as file:   # safer way to open the file (and close it automatically on block exit)
    result = [[int(x) for x in l.split()] for l in file]
```

- the inner listcomp splits & converts each line to integers (making an array of integers)
- the outer listcomp just iterates on the lines of the file

note that it will fail if there are something else than integers in your file.

(as a side note, `file` is a built-in in python 2, but not anymore in python 3, however I usually refrain from using it)

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this,

```
[map(int,i.split()) for i in filter(None,open('abc.txt').read().split('\n'))]
```

Line by line execution for more information

```
In [75]: print open('abc.txt').read()
3 2 7 4

1 8 9 3

6 5 4 1

1 0 8 7
```

`split` with newline.

```
In [76]: print open('abc.txt').read().split('\n')
['3 2 7 4', '', '1 8 9 3', '', '6 5 4 1', '', '1 0 8 7', '']
```

Remove the unnecessary null string.

```
In [77]: print filter(None,open('abc.txt').read().split('\n'))
['3 2 7 4', '1 8 9 3', '6 5 4 1', '1 0 8 7']
```

`split` with spaces

```
In [78]: print [i.split() for i in filter(None,open('abc.txt').read().split('\n'))]
[['3', '2', '7', '4'], ['1', '8', '9', '3'], ['6', '5', '4', '1'], ['1', '0', '8', '7']]
```

convert the element to `int`

```
In [79]: print [map(int,i.split()) for i in filter(None,open('abc.txt').read().split('\n'))]
[[3, 2, 7, 4], [1, 8, 9, 3], [6, 5, 4, 1], [1, 0, 8, 7]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The following uses a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create a list-of-lists. It reads each line from the file, splits it up using whitespace as a delimiter, uses the `map` function to create an iterator that returns the result of calling the `int` integer constructor on each of the string elements found in the line this way, and lastly creates a sub-list from that.

This process is repeated for each line in the file, each time resulting is a sub-list of the final list container object.

```
f = input("File name? ")
with open(f, encoding="UTF-8") as file:
    data = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in file]
print(data)  # -> [[3, 2, 7, 4], [1, 8, 9, 3], [6, 5, 4, 1], [1, 0, 8, 7]]
```

Comment: Do you think you'd be able to add to the body of your answer to give a description of how your code functions?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('intFile.txt') as f:
    res = [[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in f]
    with open('intList.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(res))
```

Adding to accepted answer. If you want to write that list to file, you need to open file and write as string as `write` only accepts string.